# How to implement running balance in vue.js loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table with monetary transactions and I want to show a running balance of sorts.

```
Initial Balance: 1000.00

| ID | Amount | Balance |
|----|--------|---------| 
|  1 | 100.00 |  900.00 |
|  2 | 150.00 |  750.00 | 
|  3 | 125.00 |  625.00 |
```

In my js data array, I have:

```
data: [

  balance: 1000.00,

  transactions: [
    { id: 1, amount: 100.00 },
    { id: 2, amount: 150.00 },
    { id: 3, amount: 125.00 },
  ],

],
```

In my view, I have:

```
<tr v-for="transaction in transactions">
  <td>{{ transaction.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ transaction.amount }}</td>
  <td>{{ balance -= transaction.amount }}</td>
</tr>
```

However, the value doesn't display the correct value and I get

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop for watcher with expression "balance -= transaction.amount"

Any ideas how to implement this properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest a computed property like Taylor did, but take another approach: Calculate all remaining Balances in a computed proerty as an Array, and then get the matching value in the template for each `$index`

```
computed: {
  remainingBalance: function () {
    var tempBalance = this.balance
    return this.transactions.map((transaction) {
      return tempBalance -= transaction.amount
    })
    // [900, 750, 635]
  }
}
```

template:

```
<tr v-for="transaction in transactions">
  <td>{{ transaction.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ transaction.amount }}</td>
  <td>{{ remainingBalance[$index] }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because every time `balance` is updated, it causes a lifecycle event and attempts to set `balance` again. This is happening in the `balance -= transaction.amount` expression. What you'll want to do is create a computed property, or create a method to calculate the remaining balance.

Something like this:

```
computed: {
  remainingBalance () {
    this.balance - this.transactions.reduce((c,a) => c + a.amount, 0)
  }
}
```

or as a method:

```
methods: {
  remainingBalance(balance, transactions) {
    balance - transactions.reduce((c,a) => c + a.amount, 0)
  }
}
```

and then in your `v-for` you would replace `balance -= transaction.amount` with `remainingBalance` or `remainingBalance(balance, transactions)` (depending on if you choose to use a computed property or a method, respectively)

If you need an explanation on what `Array.prototype.reduce` does, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Some more modifications to the original answers for the correct working. We have to define index also

```
remainingBalance: function () {
            var tempBalance = this.balance
            return this.collection.map(function(transaction) {
                    tempBalance += (transaction.amount)
                    return parseFloat( tempBalance).toFixed(2)

            },0);
            // [900.00, 750.00, 635.00]
        },


<tr v-for="transaction in transactions">
  <td>{{ transaction.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ transaction.amount }}</td>
  <td>{{ remainingBalance[index] }}</td>
</tr>
```